# Can't Create New Columns in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, azure-sql-database, ssms

As per the image below; I have no options to design the table or add new rows to my table.  I can create a new table; but not modify the existing.  Why won't it let me add a new column to my table?  I am connecting to an Azure database.

[image]

Comment: Do you really want to right-click to `add new rows`? That's what an `INSERT` is for. Now, about the `Design` option missing - what version and edition of Management Studio are you using?

Comment: Usually there is an option to "Add new column" when you right-click the column menu.  I am using SSMS 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the version of Management Studio you are using is >= that of your Azure database. I think that means you should be using SQL Server 2012's version of Management Studio. If you don't have access to that, you can get the [free, no-longer-license-encumbered 2012 version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579). Click download, then scroll to the bottom, and choose whichever SQLManagementStudio file is appropriate for your language and platform (hopefully 64-bit, and it has to be > XP).

Of course, a better way to add a column is:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Loo...
  ADD NewColumn INT;
```

Not only do you not have to rely on potentially buggy UI disasters, you can also store that in source control, which is much tougher to do when you've run a series of points and clicks.